# How to add dynamic data attribute value to a button and a div generated by repeater.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, repeater

I am using repeater.js to repeat a div with some input fields and button, but the problem is that i want to give each and every div a unique id so that i can extract data from all the fields of that particular div input elements.

this is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-group mt-repeater">
      <a href="javascript:;" data-repeater-create class="btn btn-circle purple mt-repeater-add">
         <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Repeat Field
      </a>
<div data-repeater-list="group-b">
<div data-repeater-item class="mt-repeater-item">
    <div class="mt-repeater-cell">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="dosage_form" class="form-control typeahead-findings circle-input" placeholder="Dosage Form">
                        <label for="dosage_form">e.g. Tablet / Syrup / Capsule etc.</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="brand_name" class="form-control typeahead-findings circle-input" placeholder="Brand / Generic Name">
                        <label for="brand_name">e.g. Dytor</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control circle-input" id="contents" type="text" placeholder="Contents" />
                    <span class="help-block"> e.g Paracetamol </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="dose" class="form-control typeahead-findings circle-input" placeholder="Dose">
                        <label for="dose">e.g. 20 mg / 20 ml</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control circle-input" id="dose_regimen" type="text" placeholder="Dose Regimen" />
                    <span class="help-block"> e.g 1-1-1-1 </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="therapy_duration" class="form-control typeahead-findings circle-input" placeholder="Therapy Duration">
                        <label for="therapy_duration">e.g. 1 Day / 1 Month etc.</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn green-meadow mt-repeater-delete mt-repeater-del-right mt-repeater-btn-inline addData btn-circle"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <a href="javascript:;" data-repeater-delete class="btn btn-danger mt-repeater-delete mt-repeater-del-right mt-repeater-btn-inline btn-circle"> <i class="fa fa-minus"></i> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

every time i click on the add repater button this div gets replicated but what i also want is that the new div generated should have a unique div id also the curresponding elemnts inside it should have a class or id starting with that id so that data extraction can be easy for that particular div

I was using this Jquery code:

```
$(".addData").on('click' ,function()
        {
            alert("hi");
        });
```

This is the repeater i am using: https://pastebin.com/n7g7tdTH

but this code only runs for the very first div on the later generated dynamic divs it doesn't run. I also tried editing the repeater.js but no success because its all dynamic and i am not able to understand where i should edit that code to add a dynamic data-counter value for the div and the corresponding elements.

Can anyone help with this logic?

Comment: `but this code only runs for the very first div `  `$(".addData").on('click' ,function()`  try changing to a delegated event.  `$(document.body).on('click', '.addData', function ()`

Comment: That worked bro Thanks :D but how to get the values from the input field that are present near that button

Comment: I think something like this ->  `$(this).closest('row').find('#dose_regimen').val()` etc should do the trick..

Comment: the trick didn't work

Comment: Can post the JS code for "Repeat Field" button?

Comment: This is the repeater code: https://pastebin.com/n7g7tdTH

Comment: Sorry, it's `$(this).closest('.row').find('#dose_regimen').val()`    Forgot row is a class.. so it's  `.row`

Comment: That trick worked but still its a trick might fail at some point can't we implement a permanent solution via editing the repeater.js

Comment: `trick might fail at some point`  in what way?, if you mean you might end up having a `.row` inside a `.row`, you could target something else.  eg. maybe target the `.mt-repeater-cell` as this should be more consistent.

Comment: yes even that's a legitimate point but thanks :D it worked perfectly as i wanted :D why don't u add it  as a answer in code format i will give it a green mark

Comment: Ok, will do.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem..

> but this code only runs for the very first div on the later generated
>   dynamic divs it doesn't run

You can convert your jquery events into delegated events..  These allow you to catch events on DOM elements based on a selector, so when newer DOM elements are added these are caught too.

So -> `$(".addData").on('click' ,function()`

As a delegated event becomes -> `$(document.body).on("click",".addData" ,function()`

The second problem.

> but how to get the values from the input field that are present near that button

This can be achieved by traversing up the DOM tree to a parent that surrounds the elements you want,. eg. `.row` or maybe `mt-repeater-cell`, as long as it's a DOM element that contains the elements you want to find.  Here you can use jquery's `closest` selector, that will traverse up the tree until it finds the element your after.

So -> `$(this).closest('.row').find('#dose_regimen').val()`

The above will traverse up the DOM tree until it finds a `.row` class, we then find element with id dose_regimen etc,.. `#dose_regimen` and then finally get it's value with `.val()`

Answer (score 3):

Another option, to retrieve field values would be to rename all input field **`id`** with **`name`** (example below) and use repeater.js **`repeaterVal()`** to get all the field values .

```js
$(".mt-repeater").repeater();

$("#getVal").click(function () {
 $('.mt-repeater').repeaterVal()["group-b"].map(function(fields){
                //fields contain the collection of input fields per row
  console.log(fields["dosage_form"]);
  console.log(fields["brand_name"]);
  //....
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.repeater/1.2.1/jquery.repeater.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="form-group mt-repeater">
<a href="javascript:;" data-repeater-create class="btn btn-circle purple mt-repeater-add">
<i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Repeat Field
</a>
<div data-repeater-list="group-b">
<div data-repeater-item class="mt-repeater-item">
 <div class="mt-repeater-cell">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="dosage_form" class="form-control typeahead-findings circle-input" placeholder="Dosage Form">
      <label for="dosage_form">e.g. Tablet / Syrup / Capsule etc.</label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="brand_name" class="form-control typeahead-findings circle-input" placeholder="Brand / Generic Name">
      <label for="brand_name">e.g. Dytor</label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control circle-input" nam="contents" type="text" placeholder="Contents" />
     <span class="help-block"> e.g Paracetamol </span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="dose" class="form-control typeahead-findings circle-input" placeholder="Dose">
      <label for="dose">e.g. 20 mg / 20 ml</label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control circle-input" name="dose_regimen" type="text" placeholder="Dose Regimen" />
     <span class="help-block"> e.g 1-1-1-1 </span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="therapy_duration" class="form-control typeahead-findings circle-input" placeholder="Therapy Duration">
      <label for="therapy_duration">e.g. 1 Day / 1 Month etc.</label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn green-meadow mt-repeater-delete mt-repeater-del-right mt-repeater-btn-inline addData btn-circle"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="javascript:;" data-repeater-delete class="btn btn-danger mt-repeater-delete mt-repeater-del-right mt-repeater-btn-inline btn-circle"> <i class="fa fa-minus"></i> </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<button id="getVal">Get Value</button>
```

Comment: but this code will always repeat the values which are already added in the field then whats the use of this code?

Comment: `every time i click on the add repater button this div gets replicated but what i also want is that the new div generated should have a unique div id also the curresponding elemnts inside it should have a class or id starting with that id so that data extraction can be easy for that particular div` You want to extract data from fields for each row, that's what you are asking for related to change of id's etc. When you click on the button it will allow you to read values from all fields. If this is what you are not looking for then let me know I will delete my reponse.

Comment: you have posted a working code but i wanted all the elemnts to have a unique value so that the values dont get repeated

Comment: I think you only specify `unique element id` and not `unique value`. And also got downvote :(. Changing `id` is not possible through the repeater js.

Comment: ohk make some minor edit and i will remove the down vote the vote is locked until the post is edit please let me know after don